# How to solve FATAL: Unable to load template when using jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, jsdoc3

I am facing the issues reported [here](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1436#issuecomment-1529682459) and [here](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs/issues/121) on GitHub. I am trying to add documentation for my Next.js code and following is my jsdoc config file.

```
{
  "tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true,
    "dictionaries": ["jsdoc", "closure"]
  },
  "source": {
    "include": [""],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "includePattern": "\\.(jsx|js|ts|tsx)$",
    "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "node_modules/better-docs/typescript",
    "plugins/markdown",
    "jsdoc-mermaid",
    "node_modules/better-docs/component",
    "node_modules/better-docs/category",
    "node_modules/better-docs/typedef-import"
  ],
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": false,
    "search": true,
    "default": {
      "name": "Frontend Docs",
      "title": "Frontend Docs"
    },
    "better-docs": {
      "name": "Frontend Docs",
      "title": "Frontend Docs"
    }
  },
  "opts": {
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "destination": "docs/",
    "readme": "README.md",
    "recurse": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "template": "./node_modules/better-docs"
  }
}
```

With the above configuration, jsdoc generates the documentation but without the plugins. When I change `"template": "./node_modules/better-docs"` (last line) to `"template": "better-docs"`, I get this error:

```
FATAL: Unable to load template: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\.pnpm\better-docs@2.7.2_prop-types@15.8.1_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\better-docs\publish.js/publish'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should use `"template": "./node_modules/better-docs"` for `better-docs`. However, I encountered the same issue when using `"template": "./node_modules/better-docs"`, and it showed the following error:

```
FATAL: Unable to load template: Cannot find module 'taffydb'
Require stack:
- C:\----\----\node_modules\better-docs\publish.js
- C:\----\----\node_modules\jsdoc\cli.js
- C:\----\----\node_modules\jsdoc\jsdoc.js
```

To fix this error, I used `yarn add -D taffydb`, and it resolved the issue.

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: TaffyDb was last update 7 years ago and has high severity vulerabilities.
https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-mxhp-79qh-mcx6